# Trying to insert XML data into table with "xml" data type column

Tags: python, xml, postgresql

Im trying inser a XML data into a postgresql table, in my table i have column with data type xml, my file xml is this:

`<Produtos><Guia><Descricao>dad</Descricao><QuantidadePedida>1</QuantidadePedida><QuantidadeDisponivel>1</QuantidadeDisponivel><QuantidadeparaEnvio>1</QuantidadeparaEnvio></Guia></Produtos>`

So firs i tried convert the file to string using this

`self.xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')`

And the i tried to insert

`sql ="""INSERT INTO "Guia"("Data","IdProjeto","Conteudo","NomeCli","enderecoCli","ContactoCli") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""" dados=(self.data, self.idproj,self.xmlstr, self.nomeCli, self.endereco,self.contacto)`

But i get the error

`psycopg2.errors.DatatypeMismatch: column "Conteudo" is of type xml but expression is of type bytea LINE 1: ...","ContactoCli") VALUES ('2023-05-26 00:00:00',36,'\x3c3f786... ^ HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.`

Im guiding by this tuturial [https://linuxhint.com/postgresql-xml-data-type/]

But i dont now how to solve it can anyone help me please!!:

Answer (score 0):

For python3, if you check the type you will recognize this difference:

```
self.xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml') # <class 'bytes'>
```

use instead

```
self.xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode ', method='xml') # <class 'str'>
```